# VL53L0x Array, Sensor Sync with I2C

Tags: st

I'm working on an array of VL53L0x by ST, composed of 15 sensors.
I'm using a polling policy to read the measurements coming from the Array, and each sensor in set to Continue Ranging mode and in HighSpeedMode (nominal 20ms per reading).

My problem is that when i read the array it takes like half a second to read it all, when the speed I aspected was 20ms since the sensors can work in parallel.

I call the GetMesurament() for each Sensors and, at the end, I wait for 20ms.
The measurement when i call the function must be ready, because of the continuous ranging and because I've waited for 20ms since the last time i asked for measurement. Instead it looks like I've to wait for each sensors to be ready.

I've forgotten something particular in the setting part? there is a right call procedure to do what i want?

Answer (score 0):

Since these sensors operate on I2C there is a start command to tell the module to start ranging, and in high speed mode 20ms later the value is retrieved with a read command. If your using  GetMesurament() It's sequences is probably that shown below, and made to work with only one sensor.

[image]

If you wrote your own code you could write the start commands in sequence, at 400kHz, a start command should take ~80us writing to one sensor. If you wrote the start commands in sequence, it would take ~270us. After your done writing you wait 20ms from the first one and then read all the values back in sequence.

[image]

This is assuming you have all sensors on one I2C bus, if you had multiple I2C buses you could cut your time down even more.

That is one bad thing about I2C, its nice having a 2 wire interface, but without a chip select pin there is no control over which chip get's the message on the bus and you have to wait. The only other way around this would be to bit bang the I2C yourself and put every sensor on it's own I2C bus.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Your idea seems good, but what i want to know is if there is one way to do what you propose (so asking fore measurement and retrive the results) already done in the API given by ST, without writing my own APIs, because the documentation don't cover a lot the multiple sensors cases.
PS: by the way i'm on a single I2C bus.

Comment: You will write your own API or modify ST's and you will have to spend some time to wrap your head around the I2C bus and the commands being sent, it won't be easy.  Read the datasheet a few times and write your own I2C commands. I believe ST has commands to write to the I2C so you don't have to write a module that signals the individual bits. I would appreicate it if you would vote for my question.

Comment: I've done.
By the way I don't have so much time to spend on "lower level" communication , so I still waiting for someone that have already done the same work that I'm doing that maybe have exploited this problem using the API at higher level.
Thank you for your time.

Comment: Good luck, you may want to listen to people sometime.